# Why isn't the font applied even though I set it with expo-font?

Tags: react-native, expo

**This is the `useFontsHook.js` component**

```js
    import * as Font from "expo-font";
    
    const useFontsHook = async () => {
      await Font.loadAsync({
        Nunito: require("../../assets/fonts/nunito-wght.ttf"),
        ubunturegular: require("../../assets/fonts/ubunturegular.ttf"),
      });
    };
    
    export default useFontsHook;
```

**In my `app.js` I did this**

```js
    const [fontsLoaded, setFontsLoaded] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        async function loadFonts() {
          await useFontsHook(); 
          setFontsLoaded(true);
        }
    
        loadFonts();
      }, []);
    if (!fontsLoaded) {
        return (
          <View>
            <Text>Loading Fonts...</Text>
          </View>
        );
      }
```

Every time I try to change the `fontFamily`, it doesn't seem to work. What did I do wrong here?
Also, I have an additional question. How can I set the `fontFamily` globally, similar to applying it inside HTML for web?